# MD5 Hex to Base64 String

Tags: hashing, openssl, md5

When I generate an MD5 hash with a plain-text (`password`), I get:

```
$echo -n "password" |  openssl dgst -md5 -binary | openssl enc -base64
X03MO1qnZdYdgyfeuILPmQ==
```

This works fine if I knew the plain-text, but I got an MD5 Hex string in DB (`B081DBE85E1EC3FFC3D4E7D0227400CD`) with unknown plain-text and want to convert to Binary Base64 encoded string.

```
$echo 0: B081DBE85E1EC3FFC3D4E7D0227400CD | xxd -r | openssl enc -base64
sIHb6F4ew//D1OfQInQAzQ==
```

Both the output doesn't match and I expect to get the first value (`X03MO1qnZdYdgyfeuILPmQ==`) and not the second (`sIHb6F4ew//D1OfQInQAzQ==`)

Any idea how to get a Base64 encoded string with the generated MD5 Hex string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... but I got an MD5 Hex string in DB (B081DBE85E1EC3FFC3D4E7D0227400CD) with unknown plain-text and want to convert to Binary Base64 encoded string.

While this string is the MD5 for `password` it is not the MD5 for `password` in ASCII encoding but in UTF-16LE (which is the native character encoding on Windows):

```
$ echo -n "password" | openssl dgst -md5
(stdin)= 5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99

echo -n "password" | iconv -t utf-16le | openssl dgst -md5
(stdin)= b081dbe85e1ec3ffc3d4e7d0227400cd
```

The line to decode the hex to binary and then encode it to base64 was perfectly fine, only your expectation of the result was wrong. If you have the correct expectation about the result (by using the correct character encoding) everything works:

```
$ echo -n "password" |  iconv -t utf-16le | openssl dgst -md5 -binary | openssl enc -base64
sIHb6F4ew//D1OfQInQAzQ==

$ echo 0: B081DBE85E1EC3FFC3D4E7D0227400CD | xxd -r | openssl enc -base64
sIHb6F4ew//D1OfQInQAzQ==
```

Comment: Thanks @steffen. 
Is there a way to convert UTF-16LE to ASCII encoding?

Comment: @Zeigeist: This is possible with `iconv` and other tools - see [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv) for details. Of course it is necessary that the string can actually be represented in ASCII, i.e. `password` has, while `стол` or `檯` or even `€` do  not.